# Calling a controller function to define a menu in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I've got the following code in an activeadmin resource controller....

```
ActiveAdmin.register Customer do
  menu :parent => "Accounts", :label => proc{controller.get_label()}

  controller do
    def get_label
      current_user.hasrole?(:sysadmin) ? 'Customers' : 'Your Account'
    end
```

This doesn't work. I get a "get_label not defined on CustomersController" error. However, I do have the get_label function defined on the controller, as you can see above.

Anyone have any idea how to setup a call like this (basically to dynamically determine the label to use for the customers menu item, based on the current user roles)?

Comment: You could put your function somewhere else, like your Customer model and then have `menu :parent => "Accounts", :label => proc{Customer.get_label()}`

Comment: @aruanoc If you do this, then you at least need to pass `current_user` to `get_label`.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. Seems like a reasonable question to me. I just want to be able to vary the menu text based on the logged in user.

Comment: The problem appears to be that AA renders the menus BEFORE the controller for the resource is question has been constructed fully, so any methods added to the controller aren't available at the time of the menu construction. And putting the get_label() function anywhere else would mean that the current_user (used to determine what the menu label should be) won't be available. Bottom line, looks like it's just not possible at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The proc that you are using for :label is going to be evaluated in the context of the view. In order to access its controller you can call `self.controller` which is what you are doing. The problem is that

```
menu :parent => "Accounts", :label => proc{controller.get_label()}
```

affects the view on all of the generated ActiveAdmin controllers (because the menu is a nav in ActiveAdmin that exists everywhere). So for example, if you pull up the Dashboard, `controller` will be an instance of `Admin::DashboardController` (but `get_label` is defined in your generated `Admin::CustomerController`, so you get an error). You have a couple of sane choices here.

1) put `get_label` in a helper, like application_helper and then do `proc { get_label }

2) put `get_label` in ApplicationController. In this case your call to `menu` doesn't change.

You can do a bunch of other things to make this nicer but they are *mostly* just variations of  the two options above.

**Why is a method in ApplicationController (`app/controllers/application_controller.rb`) available to my ActiveAdmin controllers?**

It turns out that when ActiveAdmin generates your controller it has the following inheritance structure:

```
  Admin::DashboardController # generated from app/admin/dashboard.rb
    extends ActiveAdmin::PageController 
      extends ActiveAdmin::BaseController 
        extends InheritedResources::Base 
          extends ApplicationController # application_controller.rb
```

Therefore, instance methods defined under ApplicationController will be available to Admin::DashboardController

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm not sure what ApplicationController you mean. The Main app controller isn't hit once you get into the activeadmin space. You must mean some ActiveAdmin App controller, but so far I haven't been able to find that. Any ideas?

Comment: @drventure BTW, what version of ActiveAdmin and Rails are you using?

Comment: ActiveAdmin 0.5.1
Rails 3.2.13

Very strange, then. I added a function to my app controller and I still got funct not defined. I'm going to try again, but restart everything. I thought I had but possibly I didn't. Thank!

Comment: Can you try activeadmin 0.6.0? Maybe do a `bundle update activeadmin`